# IntilliJ new scenario steps not being found

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, intellij-plugin, gherkin

For some reason in my automation project and new scenario steps I create in my feature files will not link to new steps.
All existing scenarios are working file for example

```
Given that I load the App in SauceLabs
```

Correctly links to

```
public void thatILoadTheAppInSauceLabs()
```

This is working with CTRL-B and I can add this to any feature. The problem is when (from today) I try to add new commands, for example I add this to a feature file.

```
Given that I load the App on localhost
```

I then use ALT-Enter to create a new step
[image]

This is then created in one of my existing step files which already has existing (working) steps, but for some reason since this morning they are failing to link
[image]
CTRL-B will not take me to the step on any new steps, only on existing ones prior to today.
ALT-Enter will still offer to create the step even though I have already done so.
[image]
Can anyone explain what has happened or what I have done please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though my pom.xml file had become corrupt, I restored yesterdays version and all good again.
Happy days